# How do I pass parameters in WooCommerce redirect..?

Tags: php, wordpress, parameters, woocommerce

I've read a related question, "Redirect to custom URL after user clicks 'Proceed to checkout' at the cart page (wordpress)" and I got that part!  But how can I pass three parameters, Product ID, Order ID and Promo Codes?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'dre_redirect_checkout');

function dre_redirect_checkout($url) {
     global $woocommerce;
     $checkout_url = 'https://........';
     return  $checkout_url; 
}
```

Comment: Means you want , product ID , order ID , etc inside the woocommerce_get_checkout_url hook?

Comment: Yes! (If possible)?

Comment: Actually, I need to send this data to salesforce, to complete the purchase, and I need to send those three parameters (product ID, order ID and Promo codes for each order!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can them via following ,

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'dre_redirect_checkout');

function dre_redirect_checkout($url) {
     global $product;
     $title = $product->title;
     $price = $product->price;
     $checkout_url = 'https://........';
     return  $checkout_url; 
}
```

Comment: Oh!  Ok!  Thank you Ahmed!